# GeoDjango real location points

Tags: geodjango, geolocation, button

I'm using GeoDjango to draw points/polygons in current location , but I'm getting this map which don't contain a geolocation button [image]

How can I add the current location button?

Here is my code:

Views.py:

```
def add_PosteHtaBt(request):
  form=PosteHtaBtaForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      messages.success(request ,'a été ajouté')
      return redirect('projet:home')
  else:
     print(form.errors)
  return render(request,'projet/form_postehtabt.html',{'form':form})
```

forms.py:

```
class PosteHtaBtaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=PosteHtaBt
        fields='__all__'
```

Comment: This tutorial might give you some ideas: https://hvitis.dev/geolocation-tutorial-geodjango-demo-and-gis-postgis-data-to-build-app-using-rest-api#calculate-points-distance

Comment: Not really , i cant get the current location in the map where i can draw objects